# What types of websites should I choose to build using Ruby on Rails over PHP?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have read many advantages of Ruby on Rails over PHP with a platform. However, it seems like Ruby on Rails is limited compared to PHP with a platform. Is there any special types of websites, such as blog, portfolio, ecommerce, job-search, content management website and etc., where I should choose Ruby on Rails over php with a platform?

For example, I've been meaning to build a ecommerce website with multi-vendors. However, many people recommended using PHP. Also, when I looked through the popular website examples using RoR, majority of website seemed like company websites with limited contents, portfolios, or websites with video links.

Comment: No downvote from me, but there are literally hundreds of articles/blogs/etc. covering the PHP vs. RoR debate. SO is dedicated to more specific programming questions, not necessarily general discussions about the merit of one language/framework over the other. Good luck in your search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails is an MVC framework, PHP is a language. You might look into "Cake" for a proper comparison.

Rails will do anything you want it to do*. A lot of this comes from the rubygem ecosystem, most of which are usable without rails.

Out-of-the-box, with no other alterations, Rails provides really convenient places to describe your data (the models), figure out what data should be used to respond to requests (the controllers), and how to show that data as an HTML web page (the views).

*Except be faster than micro frameworks (sinatra, flask, ~ node)

I would not use rails to build something the size of Twitter or Facebook. I would definitely use Rails to build the first versions of Twitter and Facebook that hit the web.

I frequently refer to Rails as "a website in a can". As such, it is excellent for every example on your list, although it'd likely be overkill for a portfolio because you don't need the database.

Finally, if your problem is in any way a common one? If you are seeking to build a "normal" sort of website? If you think other people have solved the same problems you are trying to solve? Rails (plus gems) will do it for you, and keep you happy* while you do it.

I have an interview question: Build me a website with users who have avatar pictures. One guy literally did it one line of bash prompt, via the rails-composer tool.

Remember - There are basically two principles in RoR. One, from Ruby - "Maximize Developer Happiness", and one, from Rails - "Convention over Configuration". AKA, you will enjoy yourself, and frequently have to do nothing.